# Binding DataSource in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I want to make a custom DataGridView, which can give the user a tip when it's loading data from dataSource.

I want to know, which event should I process to achieve this? In detail, which event is triggered at the start and end of data loading?

Comment: I misread the question and I voted it to close. Don't follow me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not event that is raised when the data-binding starts but you can use `RowsAdded`

`DataBindingComplete` : Occurs after a data-binding operation has finished.

more info at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_events.aspx

Comment: What about DataSourceChanged or DataMemberChanged? Will they help me?

Comment: DataSourceChanged  Occurs when the DataSource property value has changed not when the databind starts DataMemberChanged Occurs when the DataMember property value has changed.